# Amcharts Bar Chart showing only First record in Firefox

Tags: php, javascript, charts

I'm trying to display a Bar chart using the javascripts amcharts . But bar for only the first record is showing up in Firefox, the output is ok in chrome and IE. Rest of the data is not displayed on the chart. the category and value axis show presence of multiple records but only first bar is showing up. Please help.

following is my code for your reference.

```
var lineChartData = [{
    title: new Date(2009, 10, 2),
    value: 1816},
{
    title: new Date(2009, 10, 3),
    value: 2680},
{
    title: new Date(2009, 10, 4),
    value: 1448},
{
    title: new Date(2009, 10, 5),
   value: 1848},
{
   title: new Date(2009, 10, 6),
   value: 1130},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 9),
 value: 1095},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 10),
 value: 990},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 11),
 value: 13580},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 12),
 value: 1709},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 13),
 value: 1378},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 16),
 value: 1378},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 17),
 value: 1571},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 18),
 value: 5079},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 19),
 value: 5079},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 20),
 value: 1744},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 23),
 value: 1728},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 24),
 value: 1584},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 25),
 value: 3788},
{ 
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 26),
 value: 3788  },
{
  title: new Date(2009, 10, 27),
 value: 13963},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 10, 30),
 value: 13963},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 11, 1),
 value: 1642},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 11, 2),
 value: 1642},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 11, 3),
 value: 10681},
{
 title: new Date(2009, 11, 4),
 value: 1322}];


var chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
        chart.autoMarginOffset = 0;
        chart.marginRight = 0;    
        chart.dataProvider = lineChartData;
        chart.categoryField = "title";
        // this single line makes the chart a bar chart, 
        // try to set it to false - your bars will turn to columns                
        chart.rotate = true;
        // the following two lines makes chart 3D
        chart.depth3D = 20;
        chart.angle = 30;

        // AXES
        // Category
        var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
        categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";
        categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
        categoryAxis.fillAlpha = 1;
        categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
        categoryAxis.fillColor = "#FAFAFA";

        // value
        var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
        valueAxis.title = "Income in millions, USD";
        valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0.1;
        chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

        // GRAPH
        var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        graph.title = "Income";
        graph.valueField = "value";
        graph.type = "column";
        graph.balloonText = "Income in [[category]]:[[value]]";
        graph.lineAlpha = 0;
        graph.fillColors = "#bf1c25";
        graph.fillAlphas = 1;
        chart.addGraph(graph);

    chart.write("chartdiv");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was "value:". Somehow Firefox responded fine when i changed value: to chart_value: